# A story about a teenage girl unable to follow her brother to Heaven

Tags: story-identification

I remember listening to this story as a book-on-tape as a child (this would have been the early 90s), and for some reason parts of it have stuck with me.

I think the main character was a girl in her mid-teens. The story deals with her life, but has supernatural undertones throughout. The key things I remember are:

- She was close to her grandmother, and at some point (I think about 3/4 through the book) her grandmother dies. She receives a phone call about it, but she mentions *just having felt* that it had happened.
- She had a younger brother who died. At the very end of the book his ghost appears to her and tells her that he's safe in a beautiful kingdom (implied to be Heaven) and offers to show it to her. She follows him to a hiding place he used to have, but the entrance is too small for her to fit and she's unable to follow further.

I appreciate that this isn't a lot to go on, but hopefully those key points will ring a bell with someone and I can finally learn what this book was called!